# ethernet phy(DP83848I) not detected

Tags: ethernet, u-boot

I am trying to make Ethernet phy DM83848I up from u-boot and kernel in our DM365 based custom board.
I am using TI's IPNC_RDK_V5 u-boot and kernel.

Can someone guide me on where to look in u-boot for making this phy up,
Things i have done so far,

1. I already checked , the phy(DP83848I) is already supported by the u-boot i am using currently.
2. Driver is also present in the u-boot/cpu/arm926ejs/davinci. This driver is also being built along with u-boot.
3. At hardware level i checked following,
   a. RESET_N is high, (Phy resets on active low on this pin)
   b. POWER_DOWN/INT is also high ( pin is active low).
   c. IOVDD33 pin is high ( supply to phy)
   d. Crystal frequency is 25Mhz.
       e. PIN Muxing is also fine.

During boot u-boot prints "**No ETH PHY detected!!!**".

i checked the ether.c code and i found that "adap_mdio->ALIVE" is 0 and that's the reason phy is not detected.

Can someone suggest me where/that to look to make this phy up in u-boot and later in kernel ?

Here is u-boot boot log,

```
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
DIR45 0Xc8014020
OUT_DATA45 0X11000040
SET_DATA45 0X11000040
CLR_DATA45 0X11000040
Delay for 10 seconds...
Delay done
Mux3 value 0x1affff
ARM Clock :- 297MHz
DDR Clock :- 270MHz
Inside:davinci_eth_mdio_enable
DBG: adap_mdio->CONTROL:0x41040036
DBG: adap_mdio->CONTROL & MDIO_CONTROL_IDLE:0x0
Exiting:davinci_eth_mdio_enable
DBG:MDIO State machine is not in Reset
davinci_eth_hw_init: retries i = 256
davinci_eth_hw_init: adap_mdio->ALIVE = 0
davinci_eth_hw_init: adap_mdio->ALIVE = 30453768
No ETH PHY detected!!!
ethernet init failed!
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
DM368 IPNC :>
```

Thank you in advance,

Regards,
Ankur

Comment: I had similar problem. See this [patch](http://git.denx.de/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=u-boot/u-boot-ti.git;a=commit;h=6a1df37349d6a01c505ffe5e11e5f623f3d9652e).

Comment: Hi Yegorich thank you very much for reply, I am doing phy reset not as it is done in your patch, I will do it that way and let you know the result.

Comment: Hi Yegorich, i found the problem MDC line from DM365 was not connected to phy chip so it was not getting detected.

Comment: Is the stuff working now?

Comment: Ya phy is getting detected now! :)

Comment: I will have to get hardware changes done in the board. Then i want to test ping and tftp transfer. After i do that successfully i will update answer.